# React export components based on folder structure

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui

I created a private repo so I can reuse it in my projects. In my frontend app, I want to import the components based on their specific folder structure. Basically this my structure in my reusable repo:

```
- components 
  - dialogs
    - ResponseDialog.js
    - ConfirmationDialog.js
  - form
    - BaseTextField.js
    - BaseSelect.js
- helpers
  - date.js
  - string.js
```

In my frontend I want to import it like this:

```
import { BaseTextField } from '@my-repo/components'
import { date } from '@my-repo/helpers'
```

I also want to include material ui there and I want to import it like this:

```
import { Button } from '@my-repo/mui/core'
```

instead of

```
import { Button } from '@mui/core';
```

I want this structure so I don't need to import all the material ui related repo every single time and also my components are just material ui components with modifications

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about `jsconfig.json` file.

Here is the [reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig)

Comment: Dude, this seems like a comment not an answer